# postgresql: how to join single row returned by a function into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example in postgres,  I have a table like this

```
create table mytable (
a text,
b text
)
```

and a function which returns a single row from mytable

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION single_row(param1, param2, ...) RETURNS mytable AS .....
```

Then how can I call this function mutiple times in a single query,  and get all the rows returned? Just as if I was selecting from the actual table?
something like

```
select * from { single_row(a1, a2, ...) + single_row(b1, b2, ...) + single_row(c1, c2, ...) }
```

I want the results to be like

```
   a   |   b 
-------+-------
row1.a | row1.b 
row2.a | row2.b 
.
.
.
```

Comment: How do you guarantee that the function does not retrun the same row on every call? -->> please show us your function, instead of the `....`

Comment: The rows don't need to be unique, I want them to pile up in a queue, in the end it's just as if I was selectting from an actual table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick & Dirty: You could try parsing the columns on each function, if they're not too many, e.g. if the function returns `f1` and `f2`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION single_row()
RETURNS TABLE (f1 INT, f2 INT) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT 1,2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

.. you can parse it like this:

```
SELECT 
  (single_row()).f1,(single_row()).f2,
  (single_row()).f1,(single_row()).f2;

 f1 | f2 | f1 | f2 
----+----+----+----
  1 |  2 |  1 |  2
```

.. or using multiple subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM single_row()) q1,
  (SELECT * FROM single_row()) q2

 f1 | f2 | f1 | f2 
----+----+----+----
  1 |  2 |  1 |  2
```

**EDIT**: See comments

```
SELECT * FROM single_row()
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM single_row()
```

Comment: But the final result will be a single row. Actually I want  the rows to pile up, just as if I was selecting from the actual table

Comment: In the end I editted my function to accept an array of type, and in the function body loop the array and do some stuff and return next. The union all method should work for the specific condition in my question.

Comment: @sify alright. glad you solved your problem :-) cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT single_raw(), single_raw(), single_raw() ;
```